# How do I output a Dictionary Value when iterating through something other than a KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I know how to output a key and value from a dictionary when the value is a List, when I'm iterating through the dictionary using a `foreach(KeyValuePair<string,List<int>> test in myDictionary)`, but if I have to use a different type of loop, like the below example, I'm not sure how to get the value correctly.

I'm iterating through a list, but using a dictionary, because I'm sorting alphabetically.  I know there are other ways to do this, and that isn't my question.

So, I'm trying to output the keys and their values, in alphabetical order based on the key.

```
string string1 = "A_list1";
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

string string2 = "B_list2";
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 4, 5, 7 };

string string3 = "C_list3";
List<int> list3 = new List<int> { 8, 9, 10 };

Dictionary<String, List<int>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

myDictionary.Add(string2, list1);
myDictionary.Add(string1, list2);
myDictionary.Add(string3, list3);

var sortedAlphabeticallyMyDictionary = myDictionary.Keys.ToList();
sortedAlphabeticallyMyDictionary.Sort();

foreach (string myString in sortedAlphabeticallyMyDictionary)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Key: " + myString + "\n" + "Value: " + myDictionary[myString] );
}
```

**Output**

```
Key: A_list1
Value: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

Key: B_list2
Value: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

Key: C_list3
Value: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
```

The output makes sense, because if you have a Dictionary with a List in it, you have to iterate through as a KeyValuePair in order to get the actual list out, but I'm a super C# noob, and not certain how to get the List out correctly in this instance.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this an expected result for first key? `"Key: A_list1, Value: 1,2,3"`

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)

Comment: Once I'm back at a computer I'll implement what you said, and ask questions if I have any.  Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert a `List<int>` to string representation this way:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",", list.Select(x => x.ToString())));
```

So you can use this code:

```
foreach (string myString in sortedAlphabeticallyMyDictionary)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Key: {0} \n Value: {1}" , myString, 
         string.Join(",", myDictionary[myString].Select(x => x.ToString()))) );
}
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 2):

By default when you concat an object to a string, the framework performs a implicit call to `ToString` on the object for you. The default implementation of `ToString` in the base class `object` just returns a string with the type information, as you found out. If you want any kind of alternate string representation of your list, you need to generate that string yourself (eg: by calling a method that receives the list and returns a string).

```
MessageBox.Show("Key: " + myString + "\n" + "Value: " + GetListAsString(myDictionary[myString]));
```

And then:

```
private static string GetListAsString(List<int> list) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    string commaSep = ", ";
    string sep = "";
    foreach (int val in list) {
        builder.Append(sep);
        builder.Append(val);
        sep = commaSep;
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

On a side note, if you want a sorted set of keys, each with an associated value, a [SortedDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  I wish I could accept both answer.